# Update query is not showing desired result

Tags: mysql

**Problem:**

I am trying to update a table which have four foreign keys. The query I am writing has not any error but it is showing `zero row affected`.

**Query:**

```
UPDATE `NEXG`.`homes_listing` SET `property_id` = '$propertyid', `title` = '$title', `desc` = '$desc', `display_address` = '$displayaddress', `no_of_beds` = '$noOfBeds', `no_of_baths` = '$noOfPaths', `super_area` = '$superArea', `constructed_area` = '$constructedarea',`sold_flag` = '1', `notification_flag` = '1' where relationship_id=(select id from relationship,users where relationship.id=users.relationship_id limit 1) and property_type=(select id from property_type order by id desc limit 1)and possesion_status=(select id from possession_status order by id desc limit 1) and unit_of_area=(select id from unit_of_area order by id desc limit 1)order by `property_id` desc limit 1
```

**Error:**
It is not giving any error.But also not updating my table.

Comment: If the new values provided are same as the one that exist in table, zero rows are affected :)

Comment: There is no data like this in my table. Is there any reason for this. Please check my query , is it correct?@MTahir